# Obtaining constant mechanical energy from a DC Machine

Tags: dc, dc-motor, winding

Out of the five types of dc machines:

1. Separately excited
2. shunt dc motor
3. permanent-magnet dc motor
4. series dc motor
5. compounded dc motor

which one will be the best for obtaining constant mechanical energy?

Comment: Are all of the 5 types of DC machines on your list commutator machines or are you lumping all of the brushless permanent magnet machines into one type? I suspect you are asking about constant power, not constant energy. Are you confusing motor poles with commutator segments?

Comment: You want to deliver constant mechanical power to a load yes?

Comment: @Andyaka why are you guys talking about power? I know that power and energy are different but in this case are they considered to be same? And if we are talking about obtaining constant mechanical power, then which type would be best?

Comment: No, constant energy is a finite lump of energy and is not the same as constant power. Power is energy per second, quite different.

Comment: So, if the load is removed, you want the speed to rise to infinity yes?

Comment: No. I just want to obtain a constant mechanical energy with the load still connected.

Answer (score 2):

Among the commutator DC motor types, the series motor provides the widest speed range for constant power operation. However a separately excited motor can be controlled with a combination of armature and field voltage control that might have some advantages. Which configuration is better might be determined by your definition of best. You might need to look at what is available for the specific torque and speed requirements of the application.

The use of commutator DC motors has been declining in favor of other alternatives for about fifty years. They are an interesting machine to study and students can probably learn a lot from the experience, but I don't think they are considered very seriously for use today.

I don't have enough interest in commutator motors to open a book and try to sort out the parallel paths question.